# How to kill a process by name in Python on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

For example, I want to kill 'test.py', and I tried:

```
pkill -9 test.py
```

But this doesn't work. If I am running a multiprocess program, to kill by pid will require a lots of kills due to the multiple processes used. Is there a way to kill the whole program without killing one by one using PID?

Comment: I usually do this by running `ps aux | grep python`, finding the offending process' PID and killing it by the PID

Comment: Nothing to do with Python. There is e.g. `pidof` or `pgrep`. You could also kill kust the root process and see what happens. More comfortably, use `htop` to browse processes. Note that when using `-9` you don't give the process a chance to clean up anything (like e.g. child processes), so that should not be your first choice.

Comment: The problem is that when a multiprocess program is running, it takes a lot of kills to terminate all processes initialized by that program. PID can only do for a single process. I hope there is one kill to get rid of all but not affect other processes.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope the following will help you in some way.

`pkill` - is a wrapper on `pgrep` 
`pgrep` - prints a list of matching processes and that is it. So so if you do `pgrep -l test.py` it should print list of all processes that contains that name.

So basically if you run `pgrep -l test.py` and you get any results then most likely you can kill them simply as `pkill test.py`. If you run `pkill` without any parameters it will send signal -15 which is by default.

It is a good idea to use the `pgrep` command to print the matched processes before sending signals to them. At least you will know what you sending signal to.

One more option but be careful with it. `pgrep` can sue regular expressions to match process names. For example `pgrep '^test$'`.

I hope that will help someone!